# DLL Load failed when importing PyStan on Windows

Tags: python, pystan

I am trying to import PyStan in Windows 10, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
import pystan
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\test\lib\site-packages\pystan\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  from pystan.api import stanc, stan
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\test\lib\site-packages\pystan\api.py", line 14, in <module>
  import pystan._api  # stanc wrapper
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have uninstalled PyStan and reinstalled with Pip, but I seem to be getting the same error. I use the following Python version:

```
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I also get the same error when I am not working in a virtual environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to their [documentation](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_beginner.html) pyStan is partially supported on Windows. However, do you have multiple instances of Anaconda installed on your system? couldn't help but notice the folder name Anaconda2

Comment: @gavin I only have one Anaconda version installed, which is 2, hence the folder name.

Comment: i tried installing it in a virtual environment on Python 3.7 64-bit and got the same error, the package seems to be broken.

Comment: It seems like indeed, this is a Windows problem, because I just installed it on Ubuntu 16 without any problems.

Comment: This answer might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64713567/10126125