# import pystan._api failed:ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, importerror, pystan

I have installed python 3.7 and want to do some forecasting using fbprophet (https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#python)

But I get this error when installing the package using the command (pip install fbprophet)

```
import pystan
  File "e:\repos\usf\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pystan.api import stanc, stan
  File "e:\repos\usf\venv\lib\site-packages\pystan\api.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pystan._api  # stanc wrapper
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have done some research and got to know that this is possible with conda. But I am looking for a solution without using conda.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It says in the [Pystan documentation](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html) that configuring a C++ compiler can be challenging on Windows. Following approach worked for me to install Pystan 2.17.1 and FBProphet 0.6:

1. Install C++ compiler, mingw-w64 (http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download) -> I selected this one https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/
2. Add C:<MinGW_w64 installation directory>\bin to the PATH environment variable
3. Create a distutils.cfg file with the following contents in the folder \Lib\distutils in Python install directory (in venv):

   [build]
   compiler=mingw32

   [build_ext]
   compiler=mingw32
4. pip install numpy cython
5. pip install pystan==2.17.1
6. Verify the Pystan installation (https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html)
7. pip install fbprophet==0.6

Comment: Which version of Python did you use? On Python 3.8.10 I can successfully compile pystan 2.17.1 but when I try to verify it, importing the module fails with: 

`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _api`

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been some time and I can't be sure what python version I had when posting this answer. It's most probably 3.7.7.

Answer (score 3):

Follow https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1939
I had similar issues even after installing Mingw

> `conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2`
> Solved all the errors and i am able to install fbprophet finally
> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with my Python3.6 (anaconda)

I reinstalled anaconda for all users (with admin privileges) then
"conda install -c conda-forge pystan"
later i updated all other modules

it works without any error now